# How change log severity ? When I use dotnet core with GCP Logger

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

I have a dotnet core 6.0 API project,
and it's run at GKE

My purpose is to write logs to Google Cloud
and expected got different [severity](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogSeverity) with different [LogLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

What should I do ??

there is what I did,
first,  I add Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore3 NuGet package
second, I AddGoogleDiagnosticsForAspNetCore like this

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
        .AddGoogleDiagnosticsForAspNetCore(loggingOptions: new LoggingServiceOptions
        {
            Options = LoggingOptions.Create()
        });
```

third, I add some logs in the app

```
_logger.LogDebug(msg);
_logger.LogError(msg);
_logger.LogCritical(msg);
```

but anyway I got the logs from Google Logs Explorer
like below, the severity is "INFO" which is come from a Log whose LogLevel is "Erorr"

```js
{
  "insertId": "skip",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "State": {
      "{OriginalFormat}": "Test logs of Error ",
      "Message": "Test logs of Error "
    },
    "EventId": 0,
    "Category": "Deposit.Controllers.InfoController",
    "LogLevel": "Error",
    "Message": "Test logs of Error "
  },
  "resource": {},
  "timestamp": "2022-06-10T08:52:23.672316263Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {},
  "logName": "projects/myproject/logs/stdout",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-06-10T08:52:25.967313013Z"
}
```

Is it possible to map the LogLevel to severity?

Answer (score 3):

The logs you are pasting here are not the logs captured by `Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore3` instead they seem to be the ones captured by the [GKE Logging Agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-logs). I would advise you to follow their [Support Channels](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/getting-support) to report this as a possible bug.
I'm fairly certain these are the logs captured by the agent because of `"logName": "projects/myproject/logs/stdout"` as described in [Viewing your GKE logs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs#application_logs).

The log name for `Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore3` (by default) will look like `"logName": "projects/myproject/logs/aspnetcore"` instead. If you are not able to find these logs, do please create an issue in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet and we'll be able to look into it further.

Note that you can also remove [all default logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#logging-providers) before adding `Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore3`. The console logger is configured by default in ASP.NET Core, and the GKE logging agent captures all console output, which means that by removing default logging providers you make sure you only capture logs with `Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore3`. Your code would look like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Services
    .AddGoogleDiagnosticsForAspNetCore(loggingOptions: new LoggingServiceOptions
    {
        Options = LoggingOptions.Create()
    });
```